# Detecting when an image has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Is it possible to detect - using jQuery or pure DOM manipulation / events - when an image that was injected into the document has fully loaded? For example, a script needs to replace one image with another. If it just changes the `src` attribute, the user will see an image disappear briefly (or not so briefly, depending on their connection). So, a better option would be to create a new image element in some hidden place (or, if cross-platformly possible, out of DOM entirely) and switch images only when the new one is ready. Can this be done?

EDIT: It might be a separate question, but still... Is there also a way to detect when an image has *failed* to load?

Comment: Whoever just deleted a post with jQuery `.load()` method: wrong. I was going to accept that answer because it's more flexible than DOM level 0 events that `.onload` offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `image.onload = function(){<...>}`;

Image is the actual image you want to get the load of.

```
<img src='...' id='image'>
```

In order to check if the image finished loading do the following->

```
document.getElementById('image').onload = function(){<...>}
```

or

```
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('load',function(){<...>},false);
```

If you want to check if the image failed to load do this->

```
document.getElementById('image').onerror = function(){<...>}
```

or

```
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('error',function(){<...>},false);
```

**Note**

`.addEventListener` method won't work in IE8. If you are planning on supporting it I can edit my answer.

Comment: @Septagram, check my answer (also checking if the image failed to load)

Answer (score 3):

yes you can do that by using the [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

like,

```
$('#img1').load(function(){  alert('loaded'); });
```

the alert will be displayed when the resources for that particular selector has loaded fully.

Comment: It's worth also reading the [Caveats of the load event when used with images](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and considering other options like [jquery.imageload](https://github.com/JessThrysoee/jquery.imageload).

Comment: I wonder if it should be a different question, but do you know if this event also will help me detect if an image has *failed* to load, particularly because this image does not exist (i.e. not due to a timeout)?

Answer (score 1):

The .load() event does not always work as expected and is prone to fail under different circumstances. For broadest browser support I suggest to use DeSandro's imagesLoaded (which I find to be best practice anyway): https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded